# weird optimization (remove a function) in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I met a weird optimization in GCC 4.8.2 with -O2, which removes a function.

See the following code.

increase() and increase2() are same except that there is a printf() in the latter one.

However increase() is removed if using -O2 in GCC.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void swap(uint64_t *vector)
{
    uint32_t *p = (uint32_t *)vector;
    uint32_t tmp = p[0];
    p[0] = htonl(p[1]);
    p[1] = htonl(tmp);
}

void increase(uint64_t *vector)
{
    swap(vector);
    (*vector)++;
    swap(vector);
}
void increase2(uint64_t *vector)
{
    swap(vector);
    (*vector)++;
    printf("touch...\n");
    swap(vector);
}


int main()
{
    uint64_t vector = 0xa;

    increase(&vector);
    printf("%lx\n", vector);

    increase2(&vector);
    printf("%lx\n", vector);

    return 1;
}
```

the output is :

```
a
touch...
10000000000000a
```

Why?

Thanks in advance

---

Sorry that I did not say clear.

The problem is not 'remove the function', but 'the function dose not affect on the parameter'.

Matt McNabb has pointed out the reason, the strict aliasing rule.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem you described. Seems as if both `increase()` and `increase2()` are being called... What's the problem?

Comment: Learn how to use a gnu debugger to see the execution step by step.

Comment: @WedaPashi Honestly, debugging of optimized code would be pretty confusing for a beginner. In this specific case even the `main` operations are reordered. On the other hand it's reasonable to know `gdb`, of course.

Comment: Can you check you are actually running this code and you didn't, say, have the `printf` *before* each call to `increase` ?

Comment: @dlask: Very true. I agree with you entirely. But, I doubt if that will be an issue this particular code as the output is as expected, *Undefined Behaviour*. I personally think that there is slight difference between seeing step viz execution of the code and the *actual* debugging. Seeing step-viz execution of code could really help one understand the flow of code, not necessarily in case of some issue.

Comment: @WedaPashi It is not a theory. I really executed this code under gdb.

Comment: @dlask: Oh, then sorry. I didn't have a chance to execute the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code causes undefined behaviour:

```
uint32_t *p = (uint32_t *)vector;
uint32_t tmp = p[0];
```

The memory pointed to by `vector` is an object of type `uint64_t` , however you read it via an lvalue of type `uint32_t`. This violates the strict aliasing rule.

Since your program always calls this function, the behaviour of your whole program is undefined. So you can expect to see strange optimization artifacts when the optimizer cuts out paths which lead to UB.

---

Another problem is that you are using `%lx` to print out a `uint64_t`. This won't work unless your system uses 64-bit longs. To get the right specifier, use `printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", vector);` . You may need `#include <inttypes.h>` for this.

---

After fixing the printf format specifier, my system gives the following at `-O2` and lower, or if using the `-fno-strict-aliasing` switch:

```
10000000000000a
touch...
20000000000000a
```

and garbage at `-O3`.

Comment: Having said that, I didn't think gcc did any TBAA optimization at levels lower than `-O3`

Comment: To confirm this diagnosis try building with `-fno-strict-aliasing`

Comment: I tried some old versions of gcc [using online compiler](http://goo.gl/EnBqfq). gcc 4.4.7 `-O3` did actually warn `warning: dereferencing pointer 'p' does break strict-aliasing rules`, but later versions don't. I wonder what changed there...

Answer (score 0):

If the function were actually being removed, your output would be more like:

```
touch...
a
touch...
10000000000000a
```

To answer your question, it is printing this because you told it to print those three lines in that order.

Your call to `increase()` doesn't output anything, and then you output `a` with `printf("%lx\n", vector)`.

Then, you call `increase2()` and it outputs `touch...` as designed, and then you output `10000000000000a` with `printf("%lx\n", vector)`.

---

Did you check the non-optimized output?

Answer (score 0):

I know that your question was "why". That's well-explained by @Matt McNabb. But how to fix it?

Usually compilers and CPUs prefer values over pointers because they have more (and safer) space for optimizations. So let's avoid pointer tricks completely and make just value conversions:

```
#include <endian.h>

void swap(uint64_t *vector)
{
    *vector = htobe64(le64toh(*vector));
}
```

This makes your program behaviour insensitive to optimizations.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know htobe64(). I will use it for swapping.